# How to add custom predefined content panes?

Tags: 7, panels

I've seen in a few tutorials and videos online that the following Content Panes are available:

[image: content panes]

Those that say Add links, add file, etc. For example [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vndRpEYVmRQ) also shows one called 'add page banner'. However, I don't fine how to install those content panes!

I've installed the Panels module, In-Place Editor, CTools and Custom Content Panes among others, but those are not available. How can install them? (using Drupal 7) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to a Drupal distribution called [Panolopy](https://www.drupal.org/project/panopoly). You may also want to review [this page](https://www.drupal.org/node/2289783).

Comment: I saw that thanks. Is there any way to install those things without adding the whole thing? Thanks

Comment: I'm not totally sure, but possibly.